# Rails url_for and namespaced models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails, is it possible to namespace models in modules and still get correct behavior from `url_for`?

For instance, here, `url_for` works as expected:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

# config/routes.rb
resources :users

# app/views/users/index.html.haml
= url_for(@user)    # /users/1
```

Whereas after putting the `User` model into a module, `url_for` complains about an undefined method `m_user_path`:

```
# app/models/m/user.rb
module M
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
end

# config/routes.rb
resources :users

# app/views/users/index.html.haml
= url_for(@user)    # undefined method 'm_users_path'
```

Is it possible to have `url_for` ignore the module in `M::User` and return `user_path` for `url_for(@user)` instead of `m_user_path`?

**UPDATE**

So, after almost 5 years, here's the solution, thanks to esad. This has been tested in Rails 4.2.

```
# app/models/m/user.rb
module M
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
end

# app/models/m.rb
module M
  def self.use_relative_model_naming?
    true
  end
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'm_'
  end
end

# config/routes.rb
resources :users

# app/views/users/index.html.haml
= url_for(@user)    # /users/1
```

*Note: when generating model, view and controller with `bin/rails g scaffold m/user`, the views and the controller will be namespaced, too. You need to move `app/views/m/users` to `app/views/users` and `app/controllers/m/users_controller.rb` to `app/controllers/users_controller.rb`; you also need to remove references to the module `M` everywhere except in the model `M::User`.*

Finally, the goal here was to namespace models but not views and controllers. With esads solution, the module `M` (containing `User`) is explicitly told to not appear in routes. Thus, effectifely, the `M` is stripped of and only `User` remains.

The user model can now reside in `app/views/models/m/user.rb`, the users controller lives in `app/views/controllers/users_controller.rb` and the views can be found in `app/views/users`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just define `use_relative_model_naming?` in the containing module to avoid prefixing the generated route names:

```
module M
  def self.use_relative_model_naming?
    true
  end
end
```

Comment: This is golden! Solves exactly what the OP was asking (and what I was looking for) Thanks

Comment: This method should be the first one documented in Rails API!

Comment: Note to self (and others): This must be in the module, i.e. the namespace itself, not in a class.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
namespace "blah" do
  resources :thing
end
```

Then routes will be named appropiately.

```
rake routes
```

To view all routes

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it does not solve the problem: although url_for gets informed about the model namespace, the routes (controllers) will be adapted to use the same namespace -- which is not what I need.

Thus: is it possible to setup routes to use models and controllers living in different namespaces? In other words, is there a way of influencing the behavior of url_for given a model instance, without touching controller routes?

For instance, the model M::User would be defined in app/models/m/user.rb, whereas the  the controller would be defined in app/controllers/user_controller.rb.

Comment: Also, what do you do if it's not a RESTFul resource? I have this problem and the controller I'm dealing with can't be shoehorned into a resource.

Comment: resources :things do (new line) get "foo" => "controller#action".

Comment: This is not the right answer, see my edit above. What was requested is this: put a model inside a module, *without* namespacing views and controllers. In your solution, both model, views and controllers must be namespaced.

Answer (score 3):

Specify the module on the route

```
resources :users, :module => "m"
```

or use scope to do it

```
scope :module => "m" do
  resources :users
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I overridden the url_for method on my application_helper.rb file to add the :network param on all routes from my namespace :mkp.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def url_for(options = {})
    if options.is_a?(Hash) && options.has_key?(:controller)
      if options[:network].nil? && options[:controller].match(/^mkp\//).present?
        options[:network] = @network.downcase
      end
    end
    super(options)
  end
end
```