# form_for without module and namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model named MongoidContainer::Contact. I have a controller called ContactsController. Only the model is namedspaced inside the MongoidContainer module. When I use `form_for`, like this:

```
<%= form_for @contact %>
```

It raises an exception:

```
undefined method `mongoid_container_contacts_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f99823f41e8>:0x007f9989d918c0>
```

But I want it to point to contacts_path, not mongoid_container_contacts_path.

Furthermore, the name attributes look like `mongoid_container_contact[name]` instead of `contact[name]`.

Is there a way to pass the demodulized object into form_for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can [specify the path](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#relying-on-record-identification) you want:

```
form_for @contact, url: contacts_path
```

Comment: One problem with this is that the name attributes still look like this: mongoid_container_contact[name] instead of: contact[name]. Anyway to resolve that problem?

Comment: at that point, youre going to be working against the `form_for` helper, and may just want to use the manual `form_tag` builder to more easily specify your form elements. can you post your entire form?

Comment: I don't think form_tag works with fields_for and accepts_nested_attributes_for.

Comment: can you post some of your form? I'm pretty sure you can do `f.text_field :contact, :name` to get `contact[name]` in the html

Comment: ok I need a little bit to post form because right now I am using a custom builder with dynamically populated fields that wouldn't make sense out of context.

Comment: Check this answer out. This solved all the problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404440/rails-url-for-and-namespaced-models