# Module route in Rails with form_for(@object)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, namespaces, simple-form-for

I have namespaced Controller Entities::Customers

```
class Entities::CustomersController < ApplicationController
...
end
```

and namespaced ActiveRecord model:

```
class Entities::Customer < Entities::User

end
```

in my routes.rb file i have:

```
 resources :customers, module: :entities
```

The module :entities is there because i don't want to have routes such as:

*/entities/customers* but only:

*/customers*.

The problem starts when i'm rendering my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@customer) do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :email %>
      <%= f.input :password %>
      <%= f.input :name %>
      <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

This throws error: **undefined method `entities_customer_path' for Class..**

So the error is that rails think that the correct path is with prefix entities.

Rake routes give me:

```
             Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                   Controller#Action
      customers GET    /customers(.:format)          entities/customers#index
                POST   /customers(.:format)          entities/customers#create
   new_customer GET    /customers/new(.:format)      entities/customers#new
  edit_customer GET    /customers/:id/edit(.:format) entities/customers#edit
       customer GET    /customers/:id(.:format)      entities/customers#show
                PATCH  /customers/:id(.:format)      entities/customers#update
                PUT    /customers/:id(.:format)      entities/customers#update
                DELETE /customers/:id(.:format)      entities/customers#destroy
```

Comment: provide please your routes for customer

Comment: resources :customers, module: :entities as seen in description

Comment: I've meant output of `rake routes`

Comment: OK. I've added rake routes output.

Comment: This is old but it still works in modern rails (tested in v6). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404440/rails-url-for-and-namespaced-models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after some struggling I've found a solution to this problem:

The simple_form_for(@model) generate route prefixed with entities, since it doesn't know there is scoped path in routes.

So in my `_form` partial i had to manually tell rails which route to use depending on `action_name` helper method in my partial.

```
<%
case action_name
  when 'new', 'create'
   action = send("customers_path")
   method = :post
  when 'edit', 'update'
   action = send("customer_path", @customer)
   method = :put
end
%>

<%= simple_form_for(@customer, url: action, method: method) do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :email %>
      <%= f.input :password %>
      <%= f.input :name %>
      <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Haven't you found a global solution? something Scalable to the entire project ?

Comment: I don't recall solving this in a nice way. Maybe `simple_form` has fixed it by now, or potentially it's Rails issue which have been fixed in Rails 5. I don't remember which part of code actually generated the incorrect route.

Comment: I've just had this problem with form_with, and I've added an answer, it is like a global solution as asked for

Answer (score 0):

A global solution for all project can be overriding `ApplicationHelper` method `form_with` (currently in Rails 5):

in **aplication_helper.rb**

```
  def form_with(**options)
    if options[:model]
      class_name = options[:model].class.name.demodulize.underscore
      create_route_name = class_name.pluralize

      options[:scope] = class_name
      options[:url] = if options[:model].new_record?
                        send("#{create_route_name}_path")
                        # form action = "customers_path"
                      else
                        send("#{class_name}_path", options[:model])
                        # form action = "customer/45"
                      end

      # post for create and patch for update:
      options[:method] = :patch if options[:model].persisted?

      options[:model] = nil

      super
    end
  end
```

So that, in case to have routes like

```
 scope module: 'site' do
  resources :translations
 end
```

you can code in your _form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_with(model: @translation, method: :patch) do |form| %>
```

without errors