# Rails form_for route module undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having a issue with scopes.
I've defined

```
# routes.rb
resources :asientos, module:'asientos'

# app/models/asientos/asiento.rb
module Asientos
  class Asiento < ActiveRecord:Base
  end
end


# app/controllers/asientos/asientos_controller.rb
module Asientos
  class AsientosController < ApplicationController
    def new
      @asiento = Asientos::Asiento.new
    end
  end
end

# app/views/asientos/asientos/new
<%= form_for(@asiento) do |f| %>
...
```

### rake routes

```
      asientos GET      /asientos(.:format)                                       asientos/asientos#index
               POST     /asientos(.:format)                                       asientos/asientos#create
   new_asiento GET      /asientos/new(.:format)                                   asientos/asientos#new
  edit_asiento GET      /asientos/:id/edit(.:format)                              asientos/asientos#edit
       asiento GET      /asientos/:id(.:format)                                   asientos/asientos#show
               PATCH    /asientos/:id(.:format)                                   asientos/asientos#update
               PUT      /asientos/:id(.:format)                                   asientos/asientos#update
               DELETE   /asientos/:id(.:format)                                   asientos/asientos#destroy
```

Now whenever the form tries to render, i get

```
undefined method `asientos_asiento_index_path' for #<#<Class:0x000000065b3b40>:0x00000006ba5f30>
```

I've seen some of the answers like

[form_for and scopes, rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741979/form-for-and-scopes-rails-3)

[Module route in Rails with form_for(@object)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37556575/module-route-in-rails-with-form-forobject)

But none of them present a clear solution, o suggest some kind of patching.

Furthermore, form_for now generates asientos_ prefix, and in my controller now i have to rename also params.require(:asientos) to params.require(:asientos_asientos) ... not pretty...

Any suggestions (besides undoing namespacing) would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

---

**Edit**

It seems like by adding the following to the module definition, the route is generated as expected, without the "scope"

```
module Asientos
  def self.use_relative_model_naming?
    true
  end
...
end
```

But it still wants an asientos_index_path... "undefined method `asientos_index_path'"

Comment: can you add the initialize of `@asiento`, please?

Comment: sure, added! :) thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have any other button or link in the view where the form is rendered?  if yes, can you add the code related to those as well?

Comment: nope, no "real" buttons or links, all are semantic-ui divs representing buttons and click events attached by javascript to submit the containing form. Just in case i stripped all the code inside the form_for, same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after diving into tons of articles, and code i found the answer and as some posts pointed it has to do with Inflections. 
My app has custom inflections for spanish, in which inflections look like:

```
Usuario -> Usuarios
Asiento -> Asientos
ItemAsiento -> ItemsAsiento
```

you'll notice it pluralizes the first word instead. That being said, the following piece of code from rails source extracted from  **rails/activemodel/lib/active_model/naming.rb** shows the internals of whats happening

```
 def initialize(klass, namespace = nil, name = nil)
  @name = name || klass.name

  raise ArgumentError, "Class name cannot be blank. You need to supply a name argument when anonymous class given" if @name.blank?

  @unnamespaced = @name.sub(/^#{namespace.name}::/, "") if namespace
  @klass        = klass
  @singular     = _singularize(@name)
  @plural       = ActiveSupport::Inflector.pluralize(@singular)
  @element      = ActiveSupport::Inflector.underscore(ActiveSupport::Inflector.demodulize(@name))
  @human        = ActiveSupport::Inflector.humanize(@element)
  @collection   = ActiveSupport::Inflector.tableize(@name)
  @param_key    = (namespace ? _singularize(@unnamespaced) : @singular)
  @i18n_key     = @name.underscore.to_sym

  @route_key          = (namespace ? ActiveSupport::Inflector.pluralize(@param_key) : @plural.dup)
  @singular_route_key = ActiveSupport::Inflector.singularize(@route_key)
  @route_key << "_index" if @plural == @singular
end
```

Since my class is under Asientos namespace, the @name becomes Asientos::Asiento, @unnamespaced = "Asiento", @singular = "asientos_asiento", @plural = "asientos_asiento" and here lays the issue. @route_key gets suffixed if plural and singular are both equal.

But why are those equal? Since Spanish inflections pluralize first word, and it does not know of namespaces, the "asientos_asiento" is considered plural (true from an inflections stand point but wrong since first part is namespace not model name).

I guess here conventions played me, since convetion seems to assume last part is always the model name, thus english plural will always work just fine. 
This should not happen since rails is already detecting the namespace, and it should not rely on the @name itself but strip the namespace and then singularize and pluralize without the namespace.

Monkey patch... here we go...

Thanks to everybody.

Comment: I really thought your problem was another one, take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53229344/547341, routes with scope module, do not contemple for `form_with`, and probalbly for `form_for`

Comment: I have the same problem and everythin is in english. still looking for a solution that not be monkey-patch

Answer (score -1):

you need to specify the module/namespace in the form_for helper like this:

```
<% form_for [:asientos, @asiento] do |f| %>
```

Comment: By adding that, it further nests the namespace outputting `undefined method `asiento_asientos_asiento_index_path' for #<#<Class:0x0000000408e018>:0x00000004089658>`